# Wamp mysql : ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I installed `wampserver` on my xp machine month ago.. Now when I try to connect to mysql via `phpmyadmin` or `mysql console` I get the error :

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061)

Wamp icon in the tray is green meaning it's running ok.. I checked for mysql service and it's running and using the port 3306 .. I turned off the firewall.. I tried everything and it's not working.. I eventually uninstalled wamp totally and removed all its files and re-installed it again and same error.. When I try to `telnet localhost 3306` it doesn't connect and I get the error :

> Could not open connection to the host on port 3306: connect failed

I searched the web for hours, but didn't find any working solution. It seems that many people are having the same problem and most of them didn't find the solution.

Comment: Any chance there is something else competing for port 3306? Maybe try switching ports just to see.

Comment: Already tried that.. And checked and port 3306 is not used by other programs.. I also tried `netstat -a` and I can see the port in the list and is being listened to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok .. searching the internet for more several hours I've found one little clue that actually fixed my problem.

When I type `netstat -a` I get a list of active ports including 3306 (the one mysql uses). The `Foreign Address` column for some ports is `0.0.0.0.0` but for 3306 is `[::]:0`. I'm not a network guy but it turned out that it means it's a `IPv6` port and it should be `IPv4`.

Adding the following line in the file `my.ini` under `[mysqld]` and restarting the service solved the problem.

```
bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

*Note*

- My wamp version is 2.4 and mysql version is 5.6.12 running under win XP.
- `my.ini` file for me is located at `c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12`.

Hope this helps who suffered my pain.

Answer (score 0):

In my.ini there is - for example -the entry

```
    # Secure File Priv.
    secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"
```

If this path is not (further) existing, mysql cannot be started.
You have then to put an existing path.

Answer (score 0):

I also did some research on my side I reconfigure the sql parameters then in the type and networking section you have to uncheck the open windows button Firewall ports for network access then you have to press next until closing without anything modify other

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).